# KML layer hiding Google street names

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I display polylines using KML layer on top of a google map.

These polylines represent streets, but I need to show them using KML because of application needs.

The problem is that when KML features are drawn on top of streets already in Google Maps, the street names get obscured as KML lines draw on top of them.

I would like Google maps to draw its street labels on top of polylines drawn from my KML file.

Can I control draw priority of google maps' own street labels?

I have tried to include names of polylines in the KML using Name sibling in each Placemark section but no matter what I do, names from KML do not show up in the Google maps either.

I am using API v3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KmlLayers are rendered over the map tiles.  You can either change the opacity of the polylines in the KML so the labels are visible through them or add overlays on top of the KmlLayer to show the names.  Those overlays would not be part of the KML, one option for adding them would be to use the [InfoBox utility library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.12/docs/examples.html).

Comment: Thank you. That is helpful. Will try changing the opacity. Any idea why the names contained in the KML file are not displaying when polylines are rendered? I have tried both width and outerwidth for linestyle and in either case, names contained in KML do not show up. My thinking was that since names of each street are in KML, if they would be drawn along with lines, no problem. Also, please see my second comment re a follow up question about InfoBox suggestion. Thanks

Comment: The concern I'll have with using InfoBox utility library is that polylines do not completely cover google maps' own street names. I tried changing the width of polyline using outerwidth linestyle, and it does not go wider than a certain point. Further more, at closer zoomed in levels, my street lines (sourced from KML) are not right on top of google own streets (a zoomed out levels, they appear just fine). So, I am concerned that if I display my own street name labels, they'll show up along with google's street names and will make map look clustered/not so pretty. Any thoughts re this?  Thx.

Comment: My suspicion on the labels in the KML is that they are not supported in Google Maps or the API, but it is really hard to tell from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps).  I suspect you have 2 choices: 1. hide all of the Google Maps street names using styled maps, then only the ones that you add to the map (perhaps with InfoBox) will be there, or 2. make the polylines in the KML transparent enough that you can see the Google Maps street names through them (polyline transparency is supported in KML rendered by KmlLayer)

Comment: thank you very much for being so helpful. I am new to Google Maps API and your answers cleared up a few important things for me. I wasn't sure whether I was doing something wrong or ... Knowing that KML labels are not supported in Google Maps saves from having to go in circles. Also knowing that polyline transparency is supported through KMLLayer is also a time saver. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Adel Khayata: thanks for pretty formatting my message :-) It was messed up when I pasted from clipboard. Thanks for being so kind to this newbie (it was my very first post on stackoverflow).